# display a mysql db table into datagridview in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, textbox

I am working on this project and I want to display the content of a MySQL table in a datagridview in VB.NET.

The query for the retrieving the table works fine but when I run the program it doesn't display any data in the table shown.

The code I am using:

```
Private Sub Products_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SearchTextBox.Enabled = False
    Label1.Enabled = False

    SqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    SqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=osap"
    Dim data As MySqlDataAdapter

    Try
        SqlConn.Open()
        data = New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT products.id, inventory, description, products.name, categories.name as category, price FROM products INNER JOIN branches ON products.branch_id = branches.id INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id = categories.id WHERE branch_id ='" & LoginForm.BranchIDTextBox.Text & "' ", SqlConn)
        productstable = New DataTable
        data.Fill(productstable)

        ProductsDataGridView.DataSource = productstable
        ProductsDataGridView.ReadOnly = True
        SqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    Finally
        SqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub
```

Why am I not getting any results in the DataGridView?

Comment: Firstly, you should make sure all your code is in the code-block. Secondly, you should use parameterised queries (see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html). Thirdly - have you tried running just the query in the database to see if it returns anything?

Comment: Please i the query returns data in the database but doesn't return any data in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I didn't see this - you're not binding your data:

```
ProductsDataGridView.DataSource = productstable 
ProductsDataGridView.DataBind()
```